# Stata: combine foreach with by

Tags: stata, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

My data has some missing values for the variable `issue`. I'm trying to impute the most recent past `issue` value (for that subject, identified by id1 and id2), if any. If all past `issue` values are missing, I want the code to leave the current value as missing.

I tried the below code, but Stata says `foreach` can't be combined with `by`.

```
bys id1 id2 (date): foreach v in 1(1)_n {
replace issue[n] = issue[n-v] if !missing(issue[n-v]) and missing(issue[n])==1
}
```

Is there a way to do this without using `foreach` with `by`?

Comment: Please address http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37976385/stata-dropping-observations-conditional-on-other-similar-observations before starting a new thread.

Comment: Apologies, I haven't been here for long. Should I comment that the question has been resolved, or delete the question, or write an answer incorporating your solution (much appreciated)?

Comment: All you need do is indicate what works (or doesn't work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attempted loop over observations is quite unnecessary, as Stata does that any way.

If you want to use **only** the most recent non-missing value it is likely that you want this:

```
clonevar issue, generate(clone) 
bys id1 id2 (date): replace issue = clone[n-1] if missing(issue)
```

Note the following bugs in your code apart from that you flag:

`foreach v in 1(1)_n`: `foreach` won't expand a `numlist` with `in`; nor will it evaluate `_n` for you.

`replace issue[n]`: subscripts are not allowed in that position; `replace issue` means the same thing any way.

`issue[n-v]`: you'd need a local reference there.

`and` is not a keyword: you need `&` if you want a logical "and"

`n` presumably is a typo for `_n`

See also this [FAQ on replacing missing values](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/replacing-missing-values/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, as well as the code feedback. Would this replace with the most recent non-missing value? It seems like clone[n-1] takes the most recent value regardless of whether it's missing.

Comment: See the qualification flagged above **in bold** in my answer. If the last previous non-missing value may be used, regardless of when it was, the FAQ mentioned gives a detailed discussion.

Comment: Also, replacing missing by missing would be no loss.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The FAQ helped a lot, as did your explanation. Since I want to use the last previous non-missing value, I ended up using `bys id1 id2 (date): replace issue = issue[n-1] if missing(issue)` as per the FAQ.